# Greyscale compatible colours for TikZ

Tags: color, printing

I am looking for five different colours/fill styles for the bars in a TikZ chart.  The bars are quite narrow.  I want them to be distinctive when viewed onscreen or printed in colour, but also distinctive if the same PDF file gets printed in black and white.

Can anyone recommend a good set of colour definitions?  Or some other way of filling the bars to make them distinctive in both scenarios?  A bonus (non-essential) would be if colour-blind people could also tell them apart easily.

To clarify, I do not want to produce a greyscale PDF file, or generate a separate output for black and white printing, as I have seen in some other answers.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind getting 6 colors instead? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/80522/27774

Comment: @Symbol1 unfortunately that question didn't get a conclusive answer.  The most helpful suggestion there was to use [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org).  It only recommends one 5-colour scheme as "photocopy-safe", which didn't work well for me when I tried it.  For reference, its RGB codes were ['rgb(215,25,28)','rgb(253,174,97)','rgb(255,255,191)','rgb(171,221,164)','rgb(43,131,186)']

Comment: Too bad. There is still https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

@leandriis's solution of mixing colour with a certain proportion of black or white helped me reach a solution, but I found that the colours it produced were not distinct enough when printed, either in colour or greyscale.  To make the shades distinct in greyscale, I added solid black and solid white (with a black border).  To make them more distinct in colour, I used different hues (red, green, blue).  However, my blues always came out darker than expected when converted to greyscale, so I ended up replacing blue with a grey.

Here's what I ended up with, using @leandriis's source code for the demo:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=6,
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
        ytick={0,5},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=5,
        every axis plot/.append style={
          ybar,
          bar width=10pt,
          bar shift=0pt,
          fill
        }
      ]
      \addplot[draw=black,fill=white]coordinates {(1,5)};
      \addplot[fill=black!15!white]coordinates{(2,5)};
      \addplot[fill=red!40!white]coordinates{(3,5)};
      \addplot[green!60!black]coordinates{(4,5)};
      \addplot[black]coordinates{(5,5)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It's not especially pretty, but it seemed to work!  (But any comments on more aesthetically pleasing colour combinations would be appreciated!)

[image: Colour demo image] [image: Greyscale demo image]

Comment: +1. I feel that using the color `blue!15!white` instead of `black!15!white` is slightly better (of course there is difference only in the colored version).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a basic color that you can then mix with different amounts of white and black to create five different shades of this color. In the following example, I have used blue as the base color, but the same can also be done using other colors (such as red and green, as shown in the image below).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=6,
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
        ytick={0,5},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=5,
        every axis plot/.append style={
          ybar,
          bar width=10pt,
          bar shift=0pt,
          fill
        }
      ]
      \addplot[blue!15!white]coordinates {(1,5)};
      \addplot[blue!40!white]coordinates{(2,5)};
      \addplot[blue]coordinates{(3,5)};
      \addplot[blue!60!black]coordinates{(4,5)};
      \addplot[blue!15!black]coordinates{(5,5)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The same bar charts converted to grayscale are shown next to the coresponding colored chart in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it didn't work for me in practice.  I found that with the colour and B&W printers available to me, the darker shades were not sufficiently distinct.  However, it did help me think of a working solution, which I'll put in a separate answer.

Comment: @JRI: If you wish to stay with the blue color, you might want to use `\addplot[draw=black,fill=white]coordinates {(1,5)};
      \addplot[draw=black,fill=blue!10!white]coordinates{(2,5)};
      \addplot[draw=black,fill=blue!45!white]coordinates{(3,5)};
      \addplot[draw=black,fill=blue!70!white]coordinates{(4,5)};
      \addplot[draw=black,fill=black]coordinates{(5,5)};`  The result im comparison to the colors in your answer is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPcpT.png

Answer (score 1):

The colors from the [`ninecolors`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ninecolors) package may come in hand for this task.

Here is an example using every other of the predefined blue shades:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ninecolors}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
        ytick={-1,4},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=3,
        every axis plot/.append style={
          ybar,
          bar width=15pt,
          bar shift=0pt,
          fill
        }
      ]
      \addplot[blue1]coordinates {(1,3)};
      \addplot[blue3]coordinates {(2,3)};
      \addplot[blue5]coordinates {(3,3)};
      \addplot[blue7]coordinates {(4,3)};
      \addplot[blue9]coordinates {(5,3)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is an overvies of all the defined colors `redX`, `brownX`, `yellowX`, `oliveX`, `greenX`,  `tealX`,  `cyanX`,  `azureX`,  `blueX`,  `violetX`,  `magentaX`,  `purpleX` (with `X`= a number between 1 and 9), and shades, as well as the same plots image when viewed in grayscale:

[image]

Comment: +1 for discovering my less known package. :-)