How to make a blurred line connecting nodes
In the following tikz code
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage    {tikz}
% \usepackage    {siunitx} % SI units, \SI and \ang commands
% \usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}   % There are issues with some babel packages
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    % Computing some coordinates 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
%
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.pathreplacing, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{fieldout/.pic={
  \fill circle(0.1);
  \draw [,] circle(0.25);
  }
}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477473/greyscale-compatible-colours-for-tikz
% blue!80!yellow
%----
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47704/how-to-establish-node-anchor-like-points-on-a-tikz-rectangle-path-is-there-a/47709#47709
% How to establish node-anchor-like points on a (tikz) rectangle path (is there a better method than the one described)?
% To make \rectangle to behave as a \node 
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  fitting node/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=none,
    draw=none,
    reset transform,
    fit={(\pgf@pathminx,\pgf@pathminy) (\pgf@pathmaxx,\pgf@pathmaxy)}
  },
  reset transform/.code={\pgftransformreset}
}
\makeatother

\colorlet{notblue}{Blue!90!Gray!65!white}
\colorlet{notred}{Red!85!Orange}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{correo/}}


\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{grffile}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
    every node/.style={font=\huge,  }, 
    c/.style={insert path={circle[radius=4pt]},fill=orange},
    sta/.style={circle,minimum size=1.25cm,,thick,fill=Orange,text=white, text width=2cm,align=center,
    circular drop shadow={shadow scale=1.05}},
    sta0/.style={draw,Orange,circle,minimum size=1.25cm,,thick,,text=black, text width=2cm,align=center,
    %circular drop shadow={shadow scale=1.05}
    },
    line width=0.4mm, 
    % font=\sffamily
    ]
        
    % some dimensions
    \def\hhub{4} % height of I2C hub
    \def\whub{2} % width of I2C hub
    \def\nconn{4} % num connections in hub
    \def\wbeagle{5.5} % width Beagle
    \def\hbeagle{9} % height Beagle
    \def\lpin{0.14} % side of GPIO square pin
    \def\hacc{2} % height of accelerometer detail
    \def\wacc{4} % width of  accelerometer detail
    \sffamily   
        
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (saco) at (-23,-1) {\includegraphics[height=6cm, ]{CDPRvME.png}};
        \node[above of=saco, align=center, yshift=2.5cm ] {Data acquisition};
        % \node[align=left, shift={(-2.3cm,1cm)}] at (saco.north east) {Data acquisition};

        \draw[notblue,line width=0.6cm] (-17,-1) coordinate (x1) --++ (5,0)  coordinate (xn)
                       node[below left=0.2cm,scale=1, black,text width = 4.5cm, shift={(-.30,-0.5)}] {Motor torques data stream};
        \draw[Red, line width=0.6cm] ($(x1)+(0.3,0)$) --++ (0.6cm,0) node[pos=0.5, yshift=-0cm](sig1) {}; 
        \draw[Red, Latex-, line width=0.8mm] ($(sig1)+(0,0.3cm)$) --++ (0,1.5cm) ; 
        \draw[Red, line width=0.6cm] ($(sig1)+(0.8,0)$) --++ (0.6cm,0) node[pos=0.5, yshift=-0cm](sig2) {};
        \draw[Red, Latex-, line width=0.8mm] ($(sig2)+(0,0.3cm)$) --++ (0,1.5cm) node[above, align=center, text width=7cm,black, shift={(0.1cm,0.2cm)}]{Calibration periods}; 
        \draw[Red, line width=0.6cm] ($(sig2)+(0.8,0)$) --++ (0.6cm,0) node[pos=0.5, yshift=-0cm](sig3) {};
        \draw[Red, Latex-, line width=0.8mm] ($(sig3)+(0,0.3cm)$) --++ (0,1.5cm) ; 
        
        \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (MUL) at ($(saco)+(20,0)$) {\includegraphics[height=10cm]{multi0.png}}; 
        \begin{scope}[x={(MUL.south east)},y={(MUL.north west)}]
                % \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
                % \draw[blue!70, opacity=0.2] (0.9,0.1) ellipse (0.2 and 0.3);
                \node[align=left,scale=0.8] (ANOtxt) at (1.3,0.35) {Anomalies}; 
                \node[shape=ellipse,draw,blue!50, line width=0.4mm, fill=blue!70, fill opacity=0.2, 
                      minimum width=2.1cm,
                      minimum height=3.3cm,
                             % ] (ANO) at ($(ANOtxt.west)+(-0.26,-0.15)$) {};
                             % ] (ANO) at ($(MUL.south east)+(-0.11,0.18)$) {};   
                             ] (ANO) at (0.89,0.18) {};    
                
                \node[align=left,scale=0.8] (DRIFTtxt) at (0.35,0.53) {Drift of motor torques}; 
                \node[shape=ellipse,draw,red!50, line width=0.4mm, fill=red!70, fill opacity=0.2, 
                      minimum width=3cm,
                      minimum height=0.9cm,
                              ] (DIFT) at (0.725,0.45) {};
         \end{scope}
        % \filldraw[blue!70, opacity=0.2] ($(MUL.south east)$) ellipse (1 and 1.5);
        
        % \node[inner sep=0pt,] (mhG) at ($(saco)+(15.,0)$) {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{maha0.png}};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,] (mhG) at ($(saco)+(16,0)$) {\includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{GMM.eps}};
        \draw[Red, -Latex, line width=0.8mm] (xn.east) -- ($(mhG.west)+(1.cm,0)$);
        
        
        
        \node[trapezium, ,, rotate=-90, fill=Red,text=white, drop shadow,
            trapezium stretches = true,
            text width = 3.75cm,
            align = center,
            minimum width = 5cm, 
            minimum height = 1.75cm,
            trapezium angle = 75,
            scale=1.1, 
            ](t1) at ($(saco)+(24,-1.3)$) {Distance\\threshold};
        \node[black,scale=0.8, text width=7cm, align=left, ] at ($(t1.south)+(-1,0cm)$) {Mahalanobis\\distance};
            
        \draw[Red, -Latex, line width=0.8mm,inner sep=0pt,] (mhG.east) --  ($(t1.south west) + (0,0.3)$);
        
        \draw[notblue, line width=0.8mm,-Latex] ($(sig3)+(1.5,-0.3)$) |- ($(t1.south east) + (0,-0.8)$) 
                                 node[pos=0.8, below=0.5cm,scale=0.95,black,text width = 6cm] {Model fitting};
        
        
        
        \node[trapezium, ,, rotate=-90, fill=notblue,text=white, drop shadow,
            trapezium stretches = true,
            text width = 3.75cm,
            align = center,
            minimum width = 5cm, 
            minimum height = 1.75cm,
            trapezium angle = 75,
            scale=1.1, 
            ](t2) at ($(t1.north)+(8,0)$) {Drift detection};
            
        \draw[notblue, line width=0.8mm,-Latex] (t1.north) -- (t2.south);
        
        \node[text width=7cm,align=left,scale=0.8] (GMMtxt) at ($(mhG.north)+(0,1.5cm)$) 
                                     {Multi-variate Gaussian-mixture model for calibration data};
        
        
        \draw[Red, line width=0.8mm,Latex-,] (saco.south) --++ (0,-4cm)  -| (t1.east) node[pos=0.25,above=0.2cm, black] {Anomaly detection};
        \draw[notblue, line width=0.8mm, Latex-, 
        % fill=gray,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=10,shadow xshift=0pt,shadow yshift=0pt,shadow scale=1.2-0.05}
        ] (GMMtxt.north) --++ (0,6cm)  -| (t2.west) node[pos=0.25,above=0.2cm, black] {Model recalibration};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
\end{document}


I would like to blurred the two feedback arrows as in this image:

I have been tying fading and shading packages but no one seem to result like in the above image.

It is not possible to blur or fade a path, which is drawn rather than filled, in pgf/tikz, so any solution has to either use a different toolbox or fake something.
Perhaps the best effect would be achieved by filling an area designated behind the path with a fading, but that is a cumbersome solution and I would only consider it if you have a very small number of simple paths, need a higher quality result and have time on your hands.
In truth, it does not look to me as if the path in the question is faded or blurred. It looks rather more as if the 'blur' is faked. In any case, fakery should give reasonable results when the path is reasonably narrow.
There are various levels of sophistication you might aspire to in faking the desired effect. How much work is involved depends on

how many times you draw the path (you need at least 2);
whether you tweak the path or not;
whether you draw the path separately or as a pre/post action.

The simplest case involves drawing twice and using a preaction for the 'blur'.
Here's a minimal example.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red,thick,-Latex,preaction={draw,draw opacity=.25,red,line width=5pt,-}] (0,0) |-| ++(5,-5) -| ++(5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The path shown in the question has a circle behind the arrowhead. You could do that, but it increases the complexity quite significantly. It isn't hard, but it is fiddly and it would require a transparency group to do it properly, which doesn't always work in the way you think it will and doesn't always play nicely with arrow tips. So I'd do without it and maybe increase the width of the background path, if desired, to contain the arrowhead in its entirety.
